# flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Cannot create link, path

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "FileSystemException: Cannot create link, path = 'F:\Flutter Projestes\google_ui\google_home_page_ui\windows\flutter\ephemeral.plugin_symlinks\url_launcher_windows' (OS Error: Incorrect function.
, errno = 1)".
exit code 0

How to solve the error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.